# Download only new files on an Ionic app?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to download a file from a server only if the file is new. For example, by checking the file modified date. I am using the below code to download the file, but I am stuck where I need to compare the files before downloading. Can anyone please give me a solution for this.

```
.factory('fileDownloadService',['$cordovaFileTransfer', function($cordovaFileTransfer){
return{
    fileDownload:function(){

        // File for download
        var url = "http://www.xxxxx/file-to-download.json";

        // Get file name only
        var filename = url.split("/").pop();

        // Save location
        var targetPath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + filename;

        $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, {}, true).then(function (result) {
            console.log('Download Successful');
            }, function (error) {
                console.log('Download Error');
            }, function (progress) {
                 // Progress handling
            });
    }

}}])
```

Appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: The logic has to be on the server, that means you need a backend on the server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Joerg. Can you please explain a little bit more.

Comment: Your app can't know which file is new. So, make a request from your app to your server. On your server you have a script which receives the request, looks what is the newest file and send this one to your app.